# NDK, fscanf and floating constants

Tags: android, android-ndk

We are having problems with the porting of C code over to Android.
Normally we can use `fscanf` to read the following line :

```
4818852=-0x1.5fef5d6abbaa9p-13
```

where we will use the following code :

```
uint64_t f;
double v;
fscanf(file, "%lu=%la\n", &f, &v);
```

The read works under linux, but fails under Android.

Is there a known workaround for this ?

Comment: (Not an answer to your question, but you want `long double`. The value you're reading won't fit into that variable.)

Comment: Note that it's a hex float constant, `-0x1.5fef5d6abbaa9p-13`, which corresponds to decimal `-1.678157e-04`, which fits just fine in a normal `double`. Also, e.g. on 32 bit arm, `long double` is equal to a normal `double`.

Answer (score 0):

On which Android versions have you reproduced the issue? The Android libc (Bionic) was quite lacking for quite some time, but got a rather big update around Android 5.0.

In case the fix is available in a newer version of Bionic, one potential way could be to statically link the libc. I'm not sure if the NDK provides a straightforward way of doing this, but they do at least provide `libc.a`. So by targeting a new enough SDK version and linking the libc statically, you could effectively bundle a fixed version.

Another, potentially more practical choice, would be to find a standalone implementation of e.g. `sscanf`, bundle it and combine it with e.g. the libc's `fgets`.

Comment: Android 5.0 (L, API 21) is when that support was added, so that should be working fine on devices that are at least L.

Comment: Statically linking libc is not viable for apps (it works for standalone executables, but those aren't very interesting on Android). There are global lists of threads and such in bionic, and having a copy of that in your app that doesn't match the copy in the zygote is probably bad. Networking also won't work on old devices because the protocol between libc and netd has changed (though not for a long time).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the note about statically linking. Yes, on second thought it's certainly a bad idea for apps. (I've used it occasionally for building executables with a NDK toolchain but test running them on vanilla linux.)